# createUrlTree ignores "useHash: true" RouterModule configuration

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-router

In Angular 7 single page app with "useHash: true" Router module configuration I need to generate url to a resource to be opened in a new tab.

For routing in the app window following code works as expected:

this.router.navigate(['foo', 1]);

That means, it generates url like:
http://localhost:4200/#/foo/1

Although when using following method:
const url  = this.router.createUrlTree(['foo', 1]).toString();

url is "/foo/1" - without the "#", so...

window.open(url, '_blank'); result with NOT valid url:

http://localhost:4200/foo/1

The only solution (hack) i found is quite brutal:

window.open('#' + url, '_blank');

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  useHash: true,
  onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
}
```

```
showItem(item: Item) {
  // THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED
  this.router.navigate(['item', item.id]);
}

showItemInNewTab(item: Item) {
  const url  = this.router.createUrlTree(['item', item.id]).toString();

  // THIS WORKS BUT ITS A HACK :/
  window.open('#' + url, '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the [`Location`](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) class in `@angular/common` can help you resolve this:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _urlSerializer: UrlSerializer,
    private _location: Location,
    public router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let tree = this.router.createUrlTree(['/profile']);
    // The call to Location.prepareExternalUrl is the key thing here.
    console.log(this._location.prepareExternalUrl(this._urlSerializer.serialize(tree)));
    // As far as I can tell you don't really need the UrlSerializer.
  }
}
```

When I tested this it respects the router's `useHash` setting.

Comment: as at now simply combine routerLink and target could solve it 
```
<a [routerLink]="['/inspection/report', rowData.inspectionResult.id]"
                                        class="p-button-rounded p-button-text"
                                        target="_blank"
                                        pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-paperclip">
                                    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

using Angular13+, as at now simply combine routerLink and target in  element could solve it

the new code

```
<a [routerLink]="['/inspection/report', rowData.inspectionResult.id]"
 class="p-button-rounded p-button-text"
 target="_blank"
 pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-paperclip">
 </a>
```

the old code

```
  routeToReportInNewWindows(rowData:InspectionBooking){
    let url = this.router.serializeUrl(
      this.router.createUrlTree(['inspection/report', rowData.inspectionResult.id], {relativeTo: this.route.root})
    )
    
    url = this.location.prepareExternalUrl(url);

    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
....
<a 
 (click)="routeToReportInNewWindows(rowData)"
 class="p-button-rounded p-button-text" 
 pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-paperclip">
 </a>
```